# "Unable to load the requested file" in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting

I uploaded my codeigniter site to a hosting. The initial page is loading properly (the login page), however upon logging in I'm receiving this error: "Unable to load the requested file: pendingCon_view.php". Any idea as to why this view will not load? All permissions are proper, but it still won't work. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The site works perfectly on localhost by the way.

Comment: can you please tell me url. are you using index.php or not?

Comment: Thats the URL : http://lacspice.com/SEP/ci/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not named "pendingCon_view.php", not precisely anyway. Your hosting has a case-sensitive filesystem, unlike your local computer, so on your hosting "pendingcon_view.php" and "pendingCon_view.php" are different files.

Alter your code, or the filename, whichever you feel is appropriate.

Comment: Ah, renaming did the trick. Off to rename all the files now! Thank you.